# Configure proxy to Jersey client

Tags: java, proxy, jersey

I would like to configure a proxy server to my Jersey client.
I don't want to configure the proxy to the whole application (using JVM arguments such as http.proxyHost), and Id'e rather not use Apache client.
I read [here](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/How-to-use-a-proxy-with-jersey-td6407186.html) that there is an option to do it by providing HttpUrlConnection 
via HttpUrlConnectionFactory, but I couldn't find any code example.
Does anyone know how can I do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the help of Luca, I got it done:

1. Implement `HttpURLConnectionFactory`, and override the method `getHttpURLConnection`, my implementation is (thanks to Luca):

   ```
   Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 3128));
   return new HttpURLConnection(url, proxy);
   ```
2. Before instantiating the Jersey Client, create a new `URLConnectionClientHandler`, and provide your `HttpURLConnectionFactory` in its constructor. Then create a new `Client`, and provide your `ClientHandler` in the `Client` constructor. My code:

   ```
   URLConnectionClientHandler urlConnectionClientHandler = new URLConnectionClientHandler(new MyHttpURLConnectionFactory());
   _client = new Client(urlConnectionClientHandler);
   ```

Hope that's help.

Comment: Note that this only works with Java 6 onwards - the HttpURLConnection constructor with Proxy isn't available in Java 5.

Answer (score 5):

First of all I created this class

```
    import com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HttpURLConnectionFactory;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
    import java.net.Proxy;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;

/**
 *
 * @author Aimable
 */
public class ConnectionFactory implements HttpURLConnectionFactory {

    Proxy proxy;

    String proxyHost;

    Integer proxyPort;

    SSLContext sslContext;

    public ConnectionFactory() {
    }

    public ConnectionFactory(String proxyHost, Integer proxyPort) {
        this.proxyHost = proxyHost;
        this.proxyPort = proxyPort;
    }

    private void initializeProxy() {
        proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort));
    }

    @Override
    public HttpURLConnection getHttpURLConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
        initializeProxy();
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
        if (con instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
            System.out.println("The valus is....");
            HttpsURLConnection httpsCon = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
            httpsCon.setHostnameVerifier(getHostnameVerifier());
            httpsCon.setSSLSocketFactory(getSslContext().getSocketFactory());
            return httpsCon;
        } else {
            return con;
        }

    }

    public SSLContext getSslContext() {
        try {
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new SecureTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConnectionFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (KeyManagementException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConnectionFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return sslContext;
    }

    private HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifier() {
        return new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname,
                    javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

then I also create another class called SecureTrustManager

```
    import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

/**
 *
 * @author Aimable
 */
public class SecureTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }

    public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

then after creation this class i'm calling the client like this

```
URLConnectionClientHandler cc = new URLConnectionClientHandler(new ConnectionFactory(webProxy.getWebserviceProxyHost(), webProxy.getWebserviceProxyPort()));
    client = new Client(cc);
    client.setConnectTimeout(2000000);
```

replace webProxy.getWeserviceHost by your proxyHost and webProxy.getWebserviceProxyPort() by the proxy port.

This worked for me and it should work also for you. Note that i'm using Jersey 1.8 but it should also work for Jersey 2

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
conn = new URL(url).openConnection(proxy);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how, currently I'm using `Client.create(config)`. Couldn't find any option to use `UrlConnection` when creating the client.