# Jersey client with ignore ssl with proxy setting

Tags: java, jax-ws, jersey-client

how to configure the proxy to Jersey client. I am using the code from this site https://gist.github.com/outbounder/1069465. since in my coding environment, i have to use the proxy server over the https client.

Comment: I am got answer to my question with the help few other stackoverflow question and answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

our can try urlconnection instead of jersey client which is much more easier than the jersey client

please find the below some code
With the help of few stack overflow answer and [Configure proxy to Jersey client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385259/configure-proxy-to-jersey-client),               package org.app.last;

```
            import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
            import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
            import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
            import com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HttpURLConnectionFactory;
            import com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler;

            import com.sun.jersey.core.util.Base64;

            import java.io.IOException;
            import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
            import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
            import java.net.Proxy;
            import java.net.URL;
            import java.security.KeyManagementException;
            import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
            import java.security.SecureRandom;
            import java.util.logging.Level;
            import java.util.logging.Logger;
            import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
            import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
            import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
            import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
            import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
            import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
            import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
            import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

            public class ConnectionFactory implements HttpURLConnectionFactory {

                Proxy proxy;

                String proxyHost = //ener your proxy host

                Integer proxyPort = //ener your proxy port

                SSLContext sslContext;

                public ConnectionFactory() {
                }

                public ConnectionFactory(String proxyHost, Integer proxyPort) {
                    this.proxyHost = proxyHost;
                    this.proxyPort = proxyPort;
                }

                private void initializeProxy() {
                    proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort));
                }

                @Override
                public HttpURLConnection getHttpURLConnection(URL url) throws IOException {
                    initializeProxy();
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
                    if (con instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
                        System.out.println("The valus is....");
                        HttpsURLConnection httpsCon = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
                        httpsCon.setHostnameVerifier(getHostnameVerifier());
                        httpsCon.setSSLSocketFactory(getSslContext().getSocketFactory());
                        return httpsCon;
                    } else {
                        return con;
                    }

                }

                public SSLContext getSslContext() {
                    try {
                        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new SecureTrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
                       // Logger.getLogger(ConnectionFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (KeyManagementException ex) {
                       // Logger.getLogger(ConnectionFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    return sslContext;
                }

                private HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifier() {
                    return new HostnameVerifier() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean verify(String hostname,
                                javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    };
                }
                public static void main(String[] args){
                    URLConnectionClientHandler cc = new URLConnectionClientHandler(new ConnectionFactory("enter your proxy host",enter your proxy port));
                    Client client = new Client(cc);
                    client.setConnectTimeout(2000000);
                    WebResource resource = client.resource("host url");
                    resource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                    ClientResponse response =resource .post(ClientResponse.class, "");      
                    String resp = response.getEntity(String.class);
                    //String decode = Base64.base64Decode(resp);
                    System.out.println(resp);
                }
            }


            class SecureTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                        throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
                        throws CertificateException {
                }

                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }

                public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0) {
                    return true;
                }

                public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0) {
                    return true;
                }

            }
```

Comment: Thank It worked well but the problem here your using http url connection can we get that using apache http client...

Comment: Really thanks and this is the code helps me to fix the issue with Proxy config in Jersey client. Many many thanks.....

Answer (score 3):

You can use the http client with ssl connection which will give robust feature since it has built in feature so that it will take more adavantage for u. as per ur question which rest client u can opt jersey which is more easy one.